# Rotating whole xypic by 90 degrees

Tags: rotating, xy-pic

I have a diagram drawn with xypic, for example this one:

```
\begin{displaymath}
        \xymatrix@R=36pt@C=6pt{
\quad & C_7 \rtimes C_3 \\
C_7 \ar[ur] & C_3 \ar[u] \\
\end{displaymath}
```

and I want it to appear rotated by 90 degrees. I tried "adjustbox" but it gives me a "Bad math environment delimiter" error. What can I do?

Comment: How did you apply adjustbox?

Comment: Your code is not compilable for me, add an complete MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rotating` package with whatever correct code created with `xy` package (or `xymatrix`) works correctly. See this MWE (my syntax to create a commutative diagram with `xy` is perfect) with a rotation of 90 degrees (`\begin{turn}{90}`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\xymatrix@1{A\ar[r]^<{+}&B}
\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will try! Thank you

Comment: It works! Thank you